# Discord sniping edited messages not working

Tags: discord.py

I've scrolled through other people's posts about this, ive tried reworking their code to mine, but it doesnt seem to work

```py
    snipe_message_author = {}
    @client.event
    async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
          
      snipe_message_author = message_before.author
      guild = message_before.guild.name
    
    
    @client.command()
    async def snipeedit(ctx):
      channel = ctx.channel 
      try:
          snipeEmbed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.orange(),title=f"{snipe_message_author[channel.id]}", description = f"""Original message : {message_before.content}
              
             Updated message : {message_after.content}""")
          await ctx.send(embed = snipeEmbed)
      except:
        await ctx.send(f"There are no edited messages in #{channel.name}")
```

Every time i try the code, it returns `"There are no edited messages in #*channel*"`
I think its because of the `snipe_message_author`

thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: Instead of an empty, useless `except` block, print the exception, it's basic python debugging.

Comment: You're never adding the key to the `snipe_message_author` dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Łukasz Kwieciński**'s comment says:

You never add anything to `snipe_message_author = {}`, it can't work at all. Based on other posts, you can easily come up with a solution.

**Take a look at the following code:**

```py
edited_messages = {}


@client.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    edited_messages[message_before.guild.id] = (message_before.content, message_after.content, message_before.author)


@client.command()
async def snipeedit(ctx):
    try:
        content_before, content_after, message_author = edited_messages[ctx.guild.id]

        snipeEmbed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.orange(), title=f"{message_author}",
                                   description=f"Original message : {content_before}

             Updated message : {content_after}")
        await ctx.send(embed=snipeEmbed)

    except:
        await ctx.send(f"There are no edited messages in #{ctx.channel.name}")
```

In our `on_message_edit` event, we first define what should be "saved" for our `guild` or what exactly applies.

After we define these things, they are saved in the order specified. So now we have `3` "data" stored. We query or redefine these in our `try` statement and then read them from `edited_messages` for the corresponding `ctx.guild`.